# Modify SharePoint Quicklaunch on Feature Activation

Tags: development, feature-activation, quick-launch

i want to edit the SharePoint Quicklaunch. I put the following code into the Feature Activated EventReceiver.

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection nodeCollection = spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
            SPNavigationNode heading = nodeCollection.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == headingNode);

            SPNavigationNode item = heading.Children.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Url == url);
            if(item == null)
            {
                item = new SPNavigationNode(nodeName, url);
                item = heading.Children.AddAsLast(item);
            }

            return null;
```

But the navigation is still null. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: what scope does the feature have? and where is this spweb created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs if you access quicklaunch while site is being created.Below code causes the feature activated code to wait until the site collection has been created before executing.

```
using System.Threading;


public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        //Queues changes until after site exists.  For use in provisioning.
        SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ApplyYourChanges, web.Url);
    }

private void ApplyYourChanges(object state)
    {
        string webUrl = state as string;
        Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);

        // additional conditions here -- perhaps check if a feature was activated
        while (!SPSite.Exists(uri))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                //configure the quicklaunch menu
                configureQuickLaunch(web);
            }
        }
    }

public static void configureQuickLaunch(SPWeb spWeb)
    {            
        SPNavigationNodeCollection nodeCollection = spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
        SPNavigationNode heading = nodeCollection.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Title == headingNode);
        SPNavigationNode item = heading.Children.Cast<SPNavigationNode>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Url == url);
            if(item == null)
            {
                item = new SPNavigationNode(nodeName, url);
                item = heading.Children.AddAsLast(item);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to perform

```
spWeb.update()
```

for changes to be visible.

Comment: My error appears earlier. I got an Object Reference Exception in the first line of code. In my case spWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch returns null.

Comment: can you write whole code, including spsite and spweb

Comment: I seem to remember reading somewhere that the QuickLaunch collection only stored customisations to the default ordering. Looking around, I can't find that documentation to show you, but it would explain the behavior you see if true.

So your QuickLaunch.Count == 0 is just confirming that default ordering of items is in place. You can still add nodes, if that's at all helpful;

SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
SPNavigationNode node = new SPNavigationNode("Node Name", "Node URL", true);
nodes.AddAsFirst(node);